# jest cannot detect absolute paths when using webpack resolve

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I get the following error running jest tests:

```
src/tests/components/ImageSearchApp.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@comp/Header' from 'src/components/ImageSearchApp.js'

    Require stack:
      src/components/ImageSearchApp.js
      src/tests/components/ImageSearchApp.test.js

      2 | import React from "react";
      3 | /* ========= Components ============= */
    > 4 | import Header from "@comp/Header";
        | ^
      5 | import { SearchImages } from "@cont/SearchImages";
      6 | import Footer from "@comp/Footer";
      7 | /* ========= Code ============= */

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/ImageSearchApp.js:4:1)
```

This started after I implemented resolved paths in my webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@root": path.resolve(__dirname, "./"),
        "@src": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
        "@actions": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/actions"),
        "@comp": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
        "@cont": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/containers"),
        "@img": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/img"),
        "@reducers": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/reducers"),
        "@selectors": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/selectors"),
        "@store": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/store"),
        "@tests": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/tests"),
        "@consts": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/constants"),
      },
    },
```

My absolute paths work fine in my react components, I just cannot run tests.
My jest.config.json looks like this:

```
{
  "setupFiles": ["raf/polyfill", "<rootDir>/src/tests/setupTests.js"],
  "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
}
```

That's how I run tests command in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    ...,
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json --watch",
    ...
},
```

Finally, my app structure:

```
App
|--dist
|--node_modules
|--src
|   |--components
|   |--tests
|       |--compoenent.test.js
|       |--setupTest.js 
|   |--app.js
|--jest.config.json
|--webpack.config.js
|--package.json
```

Can someone point me out the way how can I solve this issue. I want to use absolute paths in my webpack.config.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `jest.config.json` you need to set the [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) property and map the same aliases you set in webpack.

You have also the option to set paths with [modulePaths](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulepaths-arraystring).

Example:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "@root/(.*)": "<rootDir>/$1",
    "@src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    "@actions/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/actions/$1",
}
```

Comment: thanks  @luissmg Could you please illustrate it with examples? This would me more useful for those who will seek for the answer in the future.

Comment: Sure! Hope this helps and works for you :)